How to select resistors for MOSFET Gate terminal?
I need to design Buzzer circuit. While i searching for reference design in google i saw one design based on buzzer,

Here they drive a buzzer by using MOSFET. Here My doubt is, they used R23 & R24 resistor.
What is the purpose of these resistors?
Is they really needed?
If needed means, how to calculate that resistor values?
Please clear my doubt....
Thanks in advance!

The 2N7002 gate has some capacitance and R23 limits the current from whatever is driving it, which can reduce the brief surge from the MCU or whatever generates the BUZZER signal. If you don't care about potential glitches you may be happy enough with whatever the driver current internal limit is.
Somewhere between a few hundred ohms and a few KΩ is fine in this case- it's only switching at a few kHz typically. For fast-switching circuits like switching power supplies you might have a much lower value.
R24 is there so if the input goes open (or high-Z from an MCU) the gate won't drift up into the partially (or fully) conducting range by itself which could cause the MOSFET or the buzzer to overheat.
It would better be on the other side of R23, depending on how the parts and any possible wires/connectors etc. are disposed. On the side it is on, it robs the MOSFET of a bit of gate voltage so you want it to be much higher than R23. The value is not critical, something like 100kΩ is okay in this case. If you reduced it to 10kΩ and left R23 at 1kΩ you'd only get 10/11 or about 90% of the voltage at BUZZER appearing  at the gate. Whether that's okay or not depends on how much voltage you have available at BUZZER, but the 2N7002 works best with 4.5V or more on the gate. There are other transistors that work better with 2.5V or even 1.8V.

If R23 = 1k, R24 = 10k means, will it works?

@Kuralmozhi For 5V in, yes. Higher R24 would be better.

okk, thank you so much @Spehro Pefhany !
